# Python: ¿Funcionalidad equivalente a "require()" de PHP?

Tags: php, python, importación

Estoy programando una aplicación de consola con una estructura condicional múltiple en la que siempre se repite una parte del código; un ejemplo:

```
elif fase == 'canciones':

    print('\n3) Se va a generar la secuencia INSERT para la tabla "paises".')

    paisesBD = Modelo.listarPaises() #Todos los países presentes en la BD
    paisesBritanicos = {'Inglaterra', 'Escocia', 'Gales', 'Irlanda del Norte'}

    paises = Paises(archivoEntrada, paisesBD, paisesBritanicos) #Se crea el objeto paises

    print(GI.escribirArchivo(paises))  #Devuelve "Se ha escrito la secuencia INSERT..."

    input(consolidacion)

    resultado = GI.insertarBD()
    fase = GI.determinarFase()

    print(f'{resultado} en la tabla "{fase}".') #Indica cuántas filas -si alguna- se han insertado en la tabla

    GI.copiarArchivos(archivoSalida)

    escape = input(advertencia)

elif fase == 'paises':

    print('\n4) Se va a generar la secuencia INSERT para la tabla "ciudades".')

    localizacionesBD = Modelo.listarLocalizaciones()  #Todas las localizaciones (ciudad, país) presentes en la BD

    ciudades = Ciudades(archivoEntrada, localizacionesBD) #Se crea el objeto ciudades

    print(GI.escribirArchivo(ciudades))  #Devuelve "Se ha escrito la secuencia INSERT..."

    input(consolidacion)

    resultado = GI.insertarBD()
    fase = GI.determinarFase()

    print(f'{resultado} en la tabla "{fase}".') #Indica cuántas filas -si alguna- se han insertado en la tabla

    GI.copiarArchivos(archivoSalida)

    escape = input(advertencia)
```

Como se puede ver, esta parte es siempre la misma para cada `elif`:

```
input(consolidacion)

resultado = GI.insertarBD()
fase = GI.determinarFase()

print(f'{resultado} en la tabla "{fase}".') #Indica cuántas filas -si alguna- se han insertado en la tabla

GI.copiarArchivos(archivoSalida)

escape = input(advertencia)
```

¿Habría manera de incluirla en otro archivo y luego llamarla con una única línea como se hace en PHP con `require()`? Por lo que veo los `import` de Python no funcionan de la misma manera.

Comment: Solo tienes que crear una función que contenga tu código y la llamas cuando la necesites...

Comment: `import` funciona si creas una estructura de [módulos](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). En la documentación podrás encontrar ejemplos que puedes aplicar en tu caso. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

He creado el siguiente método dentro de una clase que agrupa métodos estáticos de uso repetido:

```
@staticmethod #Parte final, que siempre se repite, de cada etapa condicional -equivalente a un require() en PHP-
def repeticion(archivoSalida):

    input('Si todo está en orden, presiona "Intro" para insertar la secuencia consolidada en la base de datos.')

    resultado = GI.insertarBD()
    fase = GI.determinarFase()

    print(f'{resultado} en la tabla "{fase}".')  #Indica cuántas filas -si alguna- se han insertado en la tabla

    GI.copiarArchivos(archivoSalida)

    return fase
```

De manera que el código de ejemplo que puse antes quedaría así:

```
   elif fase == 'canciones':

        print('\n3) Se va a generar la secuencia INSERT para la tabla "paises".')

        paisesBD = Modelo.listarPaises() #Todos los países presentes en la BD
        paisesBritanicos = {'Inglaterra', 'Escocia', 'Gales', 'Irlanda del Norte'}

        paises = Paises(archivoEntrada, paisesBD, paisesBritanicos) #Se crea el objeto paises

        print(GI.escribirArchivo(paises))  #Devuelve "Se ha escrito la secuencia INSERT..."

        fase = Utilidades.repeticion(archivoSalida)

        escape = input(advertencia)

    elif fase == 'paises':

        print('\n4) Se va a generar la secuencia INSERT para la tabla "ciudades".')

        localizacionesBD = Modelo.listarLocalizaciones()  #Todas las localizaciones (ciudad, país) presentes en la BD

        ciudades = Ciudades(archivoEntrada, localizacionesBD) #Se crea el objeto ciudades

        print(GI.escribirArchivo(ciudades))  #Devuelve "Se ha escrito la secuencia INSERT..."

        fase = Utilidades.repeticion(archivoSalida)

        escape = input(advertencia)
```